# clang-format and STDMETHOD

Tags: clang-format

I like using clang-format even on Windows code, but when i have to format anything that is a COM object, some of the COM macros cause it to go wrong

Given the following class

```
class A
{
public:
    int method( int foolonglongbar1, int foolonglongbar2, int foolonglongbar3, int foolonglongbar4, int foolonglongbar5) override;

    STDMETHOD(method) (int foolonglongbar1, int foolonglongbar2, int foolonglongbar3, int foolonglongbar4, int foolonglongbar5) override;
};
```

And the following .clang-format file

```
Language:        Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
```

I get the following

```
class A {
public:
  int method(
      int foolonglongbar1, int foolonglongbar2, int foolonglongbar3,
      int foolonglongbar4, int foolonglongbar5) override;

  STDMETHOD(method)
  (int foolonglongbar1, int foolonglongbar2, int foolonglongbar3,
   int foolonglongbar4, int foolonglongbar5) override;
};
```

This is ok, except the for the STDMETHOD() call, which is just a MS macro is indenting incorrectly.

Does any one know if its possible to tell clang-format to make it indent the parameters

```
class A {
    public:
      int method(
          int foolonglongbar1, int foolonglongbar2, int foolonglongbar3,
          int foolonglongbar4, int foolonglongbar5) override;

      STDMETHOD(method)
         (int foolonglongbar1, int foolonglongbar2, int foolonglongbar3,
          int foolonglongbar4, int foolonglongbar5) override;
};
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?
There is of course // clang-format off  option but it is not a solution

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line to `.clang-format` solved the issue for me:

```
TypenameMacros: ['STDMETHOD', 'STDMETHODIMP_']
```

Comment: This worked for me only as long as it has not already split the line, but if I move the ( up onto the same line as the STDMETHOD it came out correctly. thanks

Comment: part of the problem I suspect is clang-format doesn't see the "method" as a function from the debug output I see: M=0 C=0 T=TypenameMacro S=1 B=0 BK=0 P=0 Name=identifier L=9 PPK=2 FakeLParens= FakeRParens=0 II=0x1c0c37f02a0 Text='STDMETHOD'
 M=0 C=0 T=Unknown S=0 B=0 BK=0 P=23 Name=l_paren L=10 PPK=2 FakeLParens= FakeRParens=0 II=0x0 Text='('
 M=0 C=1 T=Unknown S=0 B=0 BK=0 P=140 Name=identifier L=16 PPK=2 FakeLParens= FakeRParens=0 II=0x1c0c37f0338 Text='method'
 M=0 C=0 T=Unknown S=0 B=0 BK=0 P=43 Name=r_paren L=17 PPK=2 FakeLParens= FakeRParens=0 II=0x0 Text=')'

Comment: Yeah, it's mostly a hack rather than a proper solution (`TypenameMacros` should be used for defining types not methods/functions), but I'm not sure if there's currently any other way to prevent clang-format from breaking the formatting around such macros...